# pyforms ignores settings in settings.py

Tags: python, css, application-settings, pyforms

I made a [pyforms](https://github.com/UmSenhorQualquer/pyforms/) application and tried to add settings in settings.py, but they are ignored.

---

**settings.py**

```
PYFORMS_STYLESHEET = "style.css"
PYFORMS_STYLESHEET_LINUX = "style.css"
```

---

**style.css**

```
QLineEdit {
   background-color: red;
}
```

---

All files are in the same Folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update `conf` with `settings`.

```
from pysettings import conf;
import settings
conf+=settings
```

See [the accompany tutorial](https://github.com/UmSenhorQualquer/pyforms/blob/master/tutorials/3.CodeOrganization/PersonWindow.py).

Comment: I dont know how i overlooked that